# Search-bar not aligning in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

for some reason my **expanding search bar** won't align properly with the other items on my navbar. It shows on top while sign in and sign out is pushed below. I want them all one line like the new stack overflow navbar. What is the problem?

Both css and html shown below:

```css
body {
    padding-top: 65px;
}

.search-form .form-group {
  float: right !important;
  transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  display:block;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group:hover,
.search-form .form-group.hover {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
}
.search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3596e0;
  left: initial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linkin Park</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link0 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form action="" class="search-form">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>
          </form>
      </div>
          <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>


      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Thank you very very very much in advance! :-D

Comment: Why are you using div in a inline element of UL? I think you want your search bar below "sign out" right?

Comment: No.I want it on one line straight like the Stackover flow navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the div within `<li></li>`.

**Working snippet**

```css
body {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
.form-group {
padding-top:10px;
}
.search-form .form-group {
  float: right !important;
  transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  display:block;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group:hover,
.search-form .form-group.hover {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
}
.search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3596e0;
  left: initial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linkin Park</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link0 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="sear"><div class="form-group">
            <form action="" class="search-form">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
              <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
             </div>
          </form>
      </div></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>


      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: It seems aligned now but when you hover or use the the search bar, since it expands, the item(sign in & sign out) are pushed down and it then expands :/

Comment: @The_Pythonist But in my snippet it is working fine take a look at it.

Comment: That's the mobile view the one that shows on your snippet. But in desktop broswer it looks different.

Comment: Expand the snippet you can see it is working. go full screen.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at this, search form and 'Sign In', 'Sign Out' links are in one line. I've changed you html bit, as  tag can't hold  tags.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
.search-form-holder {
 margin: 0;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.search-form .form-group {
  float: right !important;
  transition: all 0.35s, border-radius 0s;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 0 none;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  display:block;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
.search-form .form-group:hover,
.search-form .form-group.hover {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 25px 25px 4px;
}
.search-form .form-group span.form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3596e0;
  left: initial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Linkin Park</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link0 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="form-group navbar-right search-form-holder">
        <form action="" class="search-form">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
   </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```